# PyOpenGL TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, pyopengl

I am trying to learn the basics of game programming and I have installed `pygame` and `pyopengl` for that.

MyCode:

```
import sys
import OpenGL

from OpenGL.GL import *     
from OpenGL.GLU import *    
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

def draw():
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
      glutWireTeapot(0.5)
      glFlush()

glutInit(sys.argv)
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)
glutInitWindowSize(250, 250)
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100)
glutCreateWindow("Python OGL Program")
glutDisplayFunc(draw)
glutMainLoop()

draw()
```

When I run the above code in my command prompt using

```
python test.py
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    glutInit(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.0.2a5-py2.7.egg\OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 324, in glutInit
    _base_glutInit( ctypes.byref(count), holder )
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error. Am I calling `glutinit` in a wrong way?

I am using Python 2.7.2.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your pyopengl installation:  `_base_glutInit` is `None` in `OpenGL/GLUT/special.py`.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer : I installed it using `easy_install` so what do you suggest should I do a clean install from source.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer: Your suggestion worked there was something wrong with installation. I intalled it from source and it worked fine.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer, then accept your own answer, so that this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my `PyOpenGL` installation. Earlier I installed it using `easy_install`.

So, as @Ferdinand suggested that there seems to be something wrong with your pyopengl installation.

I did a clean install using `python setup.py install` and it worked.

Answer (score 13):

I was using Python 2.7.3 on Windows 7 64-bit and had a problem causing the same symptoms as Noob.

But the above PyOpenGL reinstallation solution did not help me.

I try a longshot - installation of freeglut - and it helped!

I used Windows MSVC 2.8.0 binary package from [here](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/) and dropped both 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs to my 32-bit (c:\Windows\SysWOW64) and 64-bit (C:\Windows\System32) dirs accordingly.

Comment: I normally dislike pushing old threads, but this solution made me feel happy all works now just fine =)

Answer (score 7):

I installed **PyOpenGL-3.0.2b2** on **Python 3.2** using the setup.py install (with administrator privileges), it came out with the same error as the OP.
The setup script didn't copy the DLLS folder, so you have to copy it yourself
the whole folder **\PyOpenGL-3.0.2b2\OpenGL\DLLS**.
This worked for me, hope it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 5):

in linux os you should install **freeglut3** 
in ubuntu 12.04 :

```
 sudo apt-get install freeglut3
```

Answer (score 4):

`glutInit()` expects 2 arguments, first an int as the number of command line arguments, then a list (of arguments).
`glutInit(len(sys.argv),sys.argv)` should do as there's no `argc` in module sys.

Answer (score 4):

It appears one has to download either glut or freeglut along with pyOpenGL. And most importantly, on my 64-bit Win7 system it only worked once I placed the `glut32.dll` file in `C:\Windows\System` (NOT `C:\Windows\System32` - placing it in `\System32` did not work!)

Here's a link for glut: http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html

And freeglut: http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/

Answer (score 4):

Same exact problem was happening with me. I am using Python 2.7 on windows xp 32-bits.

Solution:

Just download **glut-3.7.6-bin.zip** from http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html, unzip, place **glut32.dll** in **C:\windows\system32** and you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with python 2.7 64 bit windows.
Install the pyOpenGL package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ . Many thanks to Christopher Gohlke for maintaining this !!

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged here on SO. Please consider [editing your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/186599) and adding a synopsis here.

Answer (score 0):

I just use python2.7.3 on windows-64bits and I met the problem.
I solved it by using an unoffical pyopengl package.
From the artical, it seems offical package doesn't support 64bits-windows.
http://codeyarns.com/2012/04/27/pyopengl-installation-notes-for-windows/

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the PyOpenGL win32 installer. It is supposed to copy over the DLLS directory from the source package (.zip) but fails to do so in my tests. This should be addressed in PyOpenGL itself, and I will do so for the next beta.

In the meantime, you can copy the OpenGL/DLLS directory from the PyOpenGL 3.1.0b2 source .zip into your site-packages/OpenGL directory to install GLUT and GLE DLLs without needing to install them into your system directories.